# Monitoring Usage of Power BI Reports

Tags: powerbi

I have assigned with a task to monitor usage of Power BI dashboards of our team. I searched a method to try out this task using usage metrics in Power BI. By following that method I cannot complete my task as per the requirement. Our dashboards are in different workspaces. So that, I want to create a system or report to monitor usage of them all together at one place. Other method is using a Power BI REST API. I want to know a proper method to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an office 365 admin, you can go to the audit logs and create a report for report usage across the organization. It will give you the raw data. If you need more data than last 30 days, you need to start storing that data. great blog on it here:

https://radacad.com/build-your-own-power-bi-audit-log-usage-metrics-across-the-entire-tenant